# Difference in values if the source region lies outside or within the nested grid domain with boundary conditions from coarser resolution

Tags: atmosphere-modelling

I want to see the anthropogenic influence of one region(source)  to another region(receptor). I would be conducting nested grid simulation. But,  the nested grid simulation will be limited to receptor region only. The boundary conditions will be given by a more coarser resolution.

So what will be the difference in result if I turned of emission from source with source lying outside or inside the Nested grid domain when the boundary condition is from coarser resolution? How much of a difference will it make?

Comment: What are you using for your boundary conditions? If you aren't modeling the emission within your domain, you have to rely on the boundary conditions to specify the amount of chemical entering your domain.

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus I will be using  using global simulation but with coarser resolution. But, since it will be coarser resolution   for  boundary conditions will it make any difference  in the value of receptor region?

Comment: If you are using a nested grid within the global model, they are likely two entirely different models (like MPAS and WRF). Nesting a global model inside a global model is redundant and wastes computations. You likely have to run the global model first, then use that as boundary conditions for the limited domain (nested) model. That is, unless your model is two radically different models smooshed into one- where you can control the nesting algorithm (two-way nesting vs one way nesting).

Comment: Oh Ok. I understood. Thank you.